# using bibtex for citation - \bibliographystyle{} numbers [1]

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, bibliographystyle

I am struggeling since quite a while, trying to change the bibliographysyle, so that in document \cite{..} appears as a number i.e. [1].
I use the following elements in my first page:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{path_to_IEEEabr/IEEEabrv,bibliography.bib}
```

Where bibliography.bib is the bib file where I save the citation data.
What do I need to change here?
So far it appears in a "abbreviated name - year sytle", i.e. [RM09].

Comment: Please check whether you have more than `\bibliographystyle` directive in your document (or in a package that's loaded in the preamble of your document).

Comment: These are the packages I use: 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{todonotes} 
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bf-nodot}{\textbf{#1}~\textbf{#2}}
\captionsetup{labelformat=bf-nodot,labelsep=colon}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
I don't see any package that could lead to a collision, do you?

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments. Edit the question and put it there, but make it a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). I can't recreate the problem with only what you've posted so far. This can't be your complete preamble, since you're using `\usepgfplotslibrary` but not `\usepackage{pgfplots}`, which gives an error (with standard document classes), and no document class is specified.